# Javascript getDate problem

Tags: javascript, getdate

I have a very weird problem with javascript's getDate function. At the start of some function, i've created a Date object using:

```
var day = new Date(date);
```

in which `date` is a unix timestamp.

I dont change the day object, but after a while I try to get the day of the month of this object, but `day.getDate()` keeps giving me the wrong value.

For example:

```
alert(day.getTime() + "-" + day.getDate() + "-"+ day.getMonth() +"-" + day.getFullYear() + "-" + day.getHours() + "-" + day.getMinutes() + "-" + day.getSeconds());
```

gives me the following result: `1290297600-15-0-1970-23-24-57`

and at some other point the result is: `1290384000-15-0-1970-23-26-24`

And this is the weird part, if you lookup the unixtimestamp 1290297600 you'll see that that's the timestamp for the 21st of november 2010 at 00:00:00 gmt (1290384000 is the next day, same time)
The timestamps are correct, but i cant make sense of the dates it gives me.
This happens to me in any browser.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp) in JavaScript doesn't take the Unix timestamp (seconds since the epoch), it actually takes the milliseconds since the epoch. If you just multiply your `date` variable by 1000 then you get the correct output.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/zXAQH/)

Comment: Sir, you are my hero for today! thank you so much, completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Time = Unix timestamp format. I added 64800 second to the time so it would be converted to Mountain Standard Time.

*timestamp 24 * 60 * 60

.getTime()//milliseconds 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

private DateField dateField1; ///////////////////////

dateField1= new DateField("Date:", DateField.DATE); f.append(dateField1);

Date d = new Date(); dateField1.setDate(d);

String TimeSeg = String.valueOf(((dateField1.getDate().getTime()/1000)+64800));